# drop-down css menu behind the actual menu (z-index)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, z-index

I'm having problem with submenu hiding behind the next line of menu. 
[image: menu]  vs 
[image: sub-menu opened]

I've searched many topics and questions and basically everyone's saying that I need to add z-index > 100 to my sub-menu. I tried that everywhere, where sub-menu's present but nothing worked.

Do you have any idea how to make it work as it should?

Here's my code:

```
#header #nav{
    float:right;
    margin:0px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}

#header #nav > li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}

#header #nav > li > a{
    color:#727272;
    border:none;
    background:none;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:700;
    height:60px;
    line-height:59px;
    display:block;
    padding:0 15px;
    background:none center bottom;
    position:relative;
}

#header #nav > li > a:hover{
    color: #0073fe;
}

#nav li ul.sub-menu{
    width:210px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #ececec;
    border-top:2px solid #0073fe;
    margin:0;
    top:96%;
    padding:0 15px;
    display:none;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 2px 50px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow:  0px 2px 50px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    margin-top:2px;        
}

#nav li ul.sub-menu > span{
    position:absolute;
    top:-6px;
    left:30px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #0073fe;
}

#nav li ul.sub-menu > li{
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}

#nav li ul li a{
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:700;
    display:block;
    padding:7px 0px;
    color:#727272;
    border:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ececec;
}

#nav li ul li a:hover{
    color: #0073fe;
}

#nav li ul li:last-child a{
    border-bottom:none !important;
}

#nav li ul li ul.sub-menu{
    margin-left: 190px !important;
    margin-top: -35px !important;
}

.slogan{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:34px;
    line-height:35px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:300;
    letter-spacing: -0.01em;
    color:#000;
    padding:0px 30px 30px;
}
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and/or create a jsfiddle of the problem

Comment: is the site address enough? [remedest.pl](http://remedest.pl)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle.  Clearly defining your problem and posting related code will get your question answered more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

So you want : `submenu > menu`; which means: `#nav li ul.sub-menu > #header/#nav`

The problem is that you set up your menu to a high z-index and not your submenu (and results in: `submenu < menu`).

z-index defines a "set a layers" where your element would be, if it's set higher than an other one, then it will appear on top of it.

You need to delete the z-index for `#header #nav` and `#header #nav>li` and instead put a high z-index to `#nav li ul.sub-menu`.

```
#nav li ul.sub-menu {
    z-index: 50; //It doesn't have to be a hundred, 50 should do, or even 5...
}
```

Comment: Well, I tried that but it didn't work :( I figured, I needed z-index of the whole #header #nav so I let it be and added z-index to #nav li ul.sub-menu like this:

`#nav li ul.sub-menu {
    z-index: 110; 
}`

And it didn't work :(